# Parceling/Transporting an EventObject in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a `CustomEvent` class which extends `java.util.EventObject` .

```
public class CustomEvent extends EventObject {
public CustomEvent(Object _src) {
 super(_src);
}
private String name;
public String getName()
 {
  return name;
 }
public void setName(String name)
 {
  this.name = name;
 }
}
```

I want to transport this Object in this way in  my Android app: - `Service` > `Notification` > `Activity`

I read that the ideal way to transport objects is to make use of a `Parcelable` and pass this object via an `Intent` but I'm not sure if I can make this class to implement `Parcelable`. If I can, then how should my `writeToParcel(..)` and `readFromParcel(..)` methods be implemented?

Since `java.util.EventObject` implements this `Serializable` interface, can't I directly pass this `Object` via the Intent even if it's not `Parcelable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `Serializable` Object via an Inent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent.putExtra("ser-object", someSerializableObject);
```

You can then get this value from the `Intent` using `getSerializableExtra(String name)` method.

While `Parselable` is the Android way of passing objects around, support for `Serializable` is still present.

Comment: +1 thanks :-). That would be the easiest and the best way to do it and this is what I'm doing right now.I'm just curious of how I can Parcel this kind of an Object if I had to. Or to be more precise would it be ok to have a class which implements both `Parselable` and `Serializable`?

Comment: @AneeshJoseph There's nothing wrong with implementing both `Parselable` and `Serializable`.  Provided all your fields are `Serializable`, you would simply add `implements Serializable` to the class declaration.  For `Parselable`, you'll need to actually implement methods `writeToParsel` and `readFromParsel`.  There is a simple example on Google's page here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html